# Props not being updated when Redux action is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Just a disclaimer - my code worked when I had problematic function in my main component. After I exported it it stopped behaving as it should. My theory is because somehow props are not being updated properly.

Anyway, I have a component, which after it's clicked it starts listening on window object and sets proper store element to "true" and depending on next object clicked acts accordingly. After incorrect object is clicked, the store should revert to false, and it does, however the props are still "true" as shown on the screenshot below.

How can I solve this? Perhaps there is a way that function could take store as parameter instead of props? Or im calling actions inproperly or im missing something completely?

Code below:

Main component (relevant parts?):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import {activate} from '../../actions/inventory'
import { setModalContent, setModalState } from '../../actions/modal';
import inventoryReducer from '../../reducers/inventory';

import {chainMechanics} from './itemMechanics/chainMechanics';


class ItemRenderer extends React.Component{

    handleBoltcuttersClicked(){
        this.props.activate('boltcutters', true);
        setTimeout(() => chainMechanics(this.props), 100)
    }

    inventoryItemRender(){
        let inventoryItem = null;
        if(this.props.inventory.items.boltcutters){
            inventoryItem = <a className={this.props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters ? "ghost-button items active " : "ghost-button items"} href="#" id='boltcuttersId' onClick={() => this.handleBoltcuttersClicked()}>Boltcutters</a>
        }
        return inventoryItem;
    }

    render(){
        let renderItems = this.inventoryItemRender();
        return(
            <div>
                {renderItems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        level: state.level,
        inventory: state.inventory
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    //dispatch w propsach
    return(
        bindActionCreators({activate: activate, setModalState: setModalState, setModalContent: setModalContent }, dispatch)
    ) 
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemRenderer);
```

File with problematic function:

```
import {activate} from '../../../actions/inventory'
import { setModalContent, setModalState } from '../../../actions/modal';

export function chainMechanics(props){
    let clickedElement;
    window.onclick = ((e)=>{
        console.log(clickedElement, 'clickedelement', props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters)
        if(props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters===true){
            clickedElement = e.target;
            if(clickedElement.id === 'chainChainedDoor'){
                props.activate('boltcutters', false);
                props.setModalContent('Chain_Broken');
                props.setModalState(true);
            } else if(clickedElement.id === 'boltcuttersId'){
                console.log('foo')
            } else  {
                props.activate('boltcutters', false);
                props.setModalContent('Cant_Use');
                props.setModalState(true);
                console.log("props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters", props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters); 
            }
        }
    })
}
```

My actions:

```
const inventoryReducer = (state = inventoryDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ACTIVE':
            console.log(action)
            return {
                ...state,
                activeItem: {
                    ...state.activeItem,
                    [action.item]: action.isActive
                }
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

How I configure store:

```
export default () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            level: levelReducer,
            modal: modalReducer,
            inventory: inventoryReducer,
            styles: stylesReducer
        }),
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
    return store;
}
```

I believe thats eveyrthing needed? If not please do let me know, I've been trying to make this work for a long time.

Screenshot:
[image: Console logs]

Comment: It kinda works when I do "                props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters = false; 
"          at the end of if statement but thats ugly I suppose

Comment: With props.inventory.activeItem.boltcutters = false; you are mutating the state, which you shouldn't do in Redux

Comment: I know I shouldnt do it, but thats the only option I have to make it work. So far I wasnt able to find other solution, and nobody pointed me in the right direction / what im doing wrong

Comment: Check out my answer, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the React's function `componentWillReceiveProps`. That would trigger a rerender like this (and also make use of next props/state):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
    console.log(next);
    this.inventoryItemRender(next);
}

inventoryItemRender(next){
        const inventory = next.inventory ? next.inventory : this.props.inventory;
        let inventoryItem = null;
        if(inventory.items.boltcutters){
            inventoryItem = <a className={inventory.activeItem.boltcutters ? "ghost-button items active " : "ghost-button items"} href="#" id='boltcuttersId' onClick={(next) => this.handleBoltcuttersClicked(next)}>Boltcutters</a>
        }
        return inventoryItem;
}

handleBoltcuttersClicked(props){
        this.props.activate('boltcutters', true);
        setTimeout(() => chainMechanics(props), 100)
    }
```

Comment: App crashes when I trigger rerender this way.  "> 29 |         if(inventory.items.boltcutters){
"   undefined boltcutters in this case.

Comment: Can you try and log the next like shown in the edit of my answer? Check if inventory exists in there

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo and missed a dot. Now it works, however the props are still not updated withing the function sadly. But maybe because i pass  chainMechanics(this.props)  it this way. Should I move this function into componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: I edited the answer again and added handleBoltcuttersClicked to get props passed as param. I didn't test the code, but it should work like that. You pass the props used in inventoryItem to handleBoltcuttersClicked and that passes it to chainMechanics

Comment: There is some errors but ill try to gifure them out soon, since I need to take care of something important at work, ill let you know if i was able to